# I am working on my app since a few days now and staggered gridview widget refused to work

Tags: flutter, dart, staggered-gridview

For a while now i've been working on an app that needs me to make use of staggered gridview library but the library doesnt seem to be working

```
     StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
          crossAxisSpacing: 16,
          itemCount: bookList.length,
          mainAxisSpacing: 16,
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) =>BookItem(bookList[index])
          staggeredTileBuilder: (_) const StaggeredTile.fit(2)),
```

These are the error messages i get even after running `flutter clear and flutter pub get`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you updated the plugin perhaps? The `StaggeredGridView` has been removed/refactored since 0.6.1 I think...

There are other options now. Have a look at the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/) for what would be the best fit for you now.

Comment: Thanks Man you saved me, i had to change the version to an older one to get my code to work :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in this line try changing the underscore to context and add a comma at the end

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) =>BookItem(bookList[index]),
```

Comment: i later encountered a problem that made me do so, thankyou. you made my day :)

Comment: Welcome toSO. You may accept answers which helped you resolve the issue. That would keep the community growing